# Magento2 addViewsCount not working on Custom Product Attribute Set

Tags: magento2, attribute-set

addViewsCount function not working on Custom Attirbute set

How to make it Working for all other product attribute sets ?

As far as i am getting, it is setting the attribute set id to default Attribute set

Please Check it here:
DashBoard -> Most Viewed

File :- vendor/magento/module-reports/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php

Line 120 :

```
$this->setProductAttributeSetId($product->getEntityType()->getDefaultAttributeSetId());
```

Line 322:

```
$this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
                'e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id AND e.attribute_set_id = ?',
                $this->getProductAttributeSetId()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `attribute_set_id` from join. Just replace

```
    $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
        'e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id AND e.attribute_set_id = ?',
        $this->getProductAttributeSetId()
    )
```

with

```
    'e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id'
```